# Do banned users receive notifications?

Tags: support, banning

If I leave a comment or write an answer to their question, would they be notified? Or the site is just dead for them?

Comment: Would you like to be the guinea pig to test it with? :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes they still receive notifications as usual. Suspended users are only prevented from interacting on the site. They can still use the site as normal for any viewing experiences.

Comment: And obviously they can't even accept an answer...OK!